# Objective-C create dictionary from array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a `NSArray` which called tableView and I am trying to put all the objects into `NSDictionary` but a little differently. My array is in alphabetical ordered and it looks as below:

[image]

What I am trying to do is place them inside an NSDictionary that I started on:

```
NSDictionary *contactDirectory = @{
                @"A" : @[],
                @"B" : @[],
                @"C" : @[],
                @"D" : @[],
                @"E" : @[],
                @"F" : @[],
                @"G" : @[],
                @"H" : @[],
                @"I" : @[],
                @"J" : @[],
                @"K" : @[],
                @"L" : @[],
                @"M" : @[],
                @"N" : @[],
                @"O" : @[],
                @"P" : @[],
                @"Q" : @[],
                @"R" : @[],
                @"S" : @[],
                @"T" : @[],
                @"U" : @[],
                @"V" : @[],
                @"W" : @[],
                @"X" : @[],
                @"Y" : @[],
                @"Z" : @[]
                };
```

so if a letter starts with A, place it in the A column. Both the Vendor_Name and Vendor need to be in there, but sorted by Vendor_Name as it already is. My Question is what is the next step to accomplish what I want

Comment: Directory or dictionary? Different things!

Comment: NSDictionary not Directory...sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create an empty dictionary:

   ```
   NSMutableDictionary *contactDirectory = [NSMutableDictionary new];
   ```
2. Iterate over your current array and insert object to the represented capital letter:

   ```
   for (NSInteger i = 0; i < tableData.count; i++) {
       NSDictionary *tmp = tableData[i];
       NSString *firstLetter = [[tmp objectForKey:@"Vendor_Name"] substringToIndex:1];
       if (![contactDirectory objectForKey:firstLetter]) {
           [contactDirectory setObject:[NSMutableArray new] forKey:firstLetter];
       }
       [[contactDirectory objectForKey:firstLetter] addObject:tmp];
   }
   ```
3. Order each child array, using sort descriptor:

   ```
   NSMutableDictionary *contactDirectoryFinal = [NSMutableDictionary new];
   NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Vendor_Name" ascending:YES];
   for (NSString *key in contactDirectory.allKeys) {
       [contactDirectoryFinal setObject:[[contactDirectory objectForKey:key] sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]] forKey:key];
   }
   ```

`contactDirectoryFinal` contains what you need.

Comment: `[contactDirectory setObject:@[] forKey:firstLetter]` probably needs to be `[contactDirectory setObject:[NSMutableArray new] forKey:firstLetter]` or your preferred form of creating a new mutable array. Otherwise that `addObject:` is going to raise an exception.

Comment: @Tommy Correct. Fixed it. Thanks

Comment: I get 3 warnings with this code: '-containsKey:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

'NSDictionary' may not respond to 'setObject:forKey:'

'NSDictionary' may not respond to 'setObject:forKey:'

Comment: You should use a NSMutableDictionary instead of a NSDictionary